# Angular ng-grid binds checkboxes and not radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've got an ng-grid with a column that has only boolean values, something like:

```
column1   column2
data1     true
data2     false
data3     false
```

Instead of using the normal cell template, I wanted to bind the boolean property to a radio button like so:

```
var toRadioButton = function(_selected){
var html = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">'+
    '<input id="radio_{{row.rowIndex}}" name="myRadio"'+
    'checked="{{row.entity.myDefault}}" type="radio" '+
    'ng-model="row.entity.myDefault"/></div>';
return html;
};
```

However, this doesn't work, angular does not pick up on the binding and leaves all three radio buttons empty (although giving them the same name means that you can only select one at a time).  If I switch out the template to be of type="checkbox", then the binding works.  Is there any reason for this to be the case, and how can I fix that?

Comment: can you put some more code as an example on http://plnkr.co/?

Comment: have you found solution?